# Update M2M relation for a Model instance in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models as follows:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class ServiceGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, through=ServiceToServiceGroup)

class ServiceToServiceGroup(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
    service_group = models.ForeignKey(ServiceGroup)
```

I have a list of services that I need to make as M2M association for an instance of the ServiceGroup. I tried the following:

```
In [145]: instance = ServiceGroup.objects.get(pk=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [146]: instance.services.all()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[146]: <QuerySet [<Service: service-1>]>

In [147]: new = ['service-2']                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [148]: service_objects = Service.objects.filter(name__in=new)                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [149]: service_objects                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[149]: <QuerySet [<Service: service-2>]>

In [150]: instance.service_set = service_objects                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [151]: instance.save()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [152]: instance.services.all()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[152]: <QuerySet [<Service: service-1>]>
```

However, as is evident, this did not work. What is the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: Do you want to create a new object and save it in ServiceToServiceGroup?

Comment: yes..even that needs to be done..also old associations need to be deleted..

Answer (score 1):

In order to create the connection you need to create a mediator instance:

```
for service in service_objects:
    ServiceToServiceGroup.objects.create(
        service=service,
        service_group=instance,
    )
```

Also you can use bulk create:

```
ServiceToServiceGroup.objects.bulk_create(
        [ServiceToServiceGroup(
            service=service, 
            service_group=instance
         ) for service in service_objects]
    )
```

For deleting old relations you can run:

```
ServiceToServiceGroup.objects.filter(service_group=instance).delete()
```

or

```
instance.servicetoservicegroup_set.all().delete()
```

Before running adding script.

Comment: However, this does not delete older associations..i need an update function where the new services get added and the older ones get deleted..

Comment: For your case I think you would need to do `ServiceToServiceGroup.objects.filter(service_group=instance).delete()` before running above add new associations script.

Comment: yeah..looks like that is the only option :-(

Comment: Also you can do it easier as `instance.servicetoservicegroup_set.all().delete()`

Comment: If my answer helped, could you mark it as a solution? Good luck!